# Waiting for specific date. Calendar Java Code Optimization

Tags: java, time, calendar, compare

I want to perform a task using Java **at specific, given hour**. My code works, but it doesn't look good. I'm comparing two strings. I tried to compare dates using getTimeInMills() but numbers aren't the same.

Here's my code:

```
import java.util.Calendar;

class Voter {
Calendar current,deadline;
boolean keepGoing = true;

public static void main(String[] args) {
    Voter strzal = new Voter();
    strzal.shoot();
}

public void shoot() {
    deadline = Calendar.getInstance();
    deadline.set(2011,6,21,11,20,00);

    while (keepGoing) {
        // wait 1 second
        try {
            Thread.sleep(1000);
            System.out.print(".");
        } catch (InterruptedException ex) { ex.printStackTrace(); }

        current = Calendar.getInstance();

        if (deadline.getTime().toString().equals(current.getTime().toString())) {
            System.out.println("Got it!");
            keepGoing = false;
        } // end of if
    } // end of while
} // end of shoot() method
```

}

I'm running in the loop, waiting for the current time to be equal to deadline (in an example I set it to 21st July 2011 11:10 AM).

**How can I improve my code?** I'd like to use for example compareTo() or getTimeInMills() method from Calendar class, but I can't set deadline properly.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using a ScheduledExecutorService is a better suggestion, however for your knowledge

```
Calendar deadline = Calendar.getInstance();
deadline.set(2011,6,21,11,20,00);
long endTime = deadline.getTime().getTime();

// later
long current = System.currentTimeMillis();
if (current >= endTime) {
    System.out.println("Got it!");
    break;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Use a [ScheduledExecutorService](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html) to manage this for you, rather than sleeping and waiting for the right time.  The [schedule](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledExecutorService.html#schedule%28java.lang.Runnable,%20long,%20java.util.concurrent.TimeUnit%29) method sounds like it'll do what you need.

Answer (score 2):

Don't reinvent the wheel! There's a JDK class for this - the [ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor.html). Here's one line of code that does it all:

```
new ScheduledThreadPoolExecutor(1).schedule(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
        // Do something
    }
}, 1, TimeUnit.HOURS);
```

This example waits 1 hour, but you can replace that with so many seconds or whatever you need.

Job done.